# Xamarin iOS Zxing with ZXingScannerView

Tags: xamarin.ios, navigation, zxing

Need to navigate to other view as soon as Scan completes 
Using Zxing with ZXingScannerView

Using this code

```
scannerView.StartScanning(async (result) =>
{
    if (!ContinuousScanning)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Stopping scan...");
        Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result.Text);
        scannerView.StopScanning();
        if (result != null)
        {
            await GetScannedDetails(result.Text);
            // here i need to navigate to other screen
        }
    }

    var evt = this.OnScannedResult;
    if (evt != null) evt(result);
}, this.ScanningOptions);
```

When i tried navigating I got this error 
Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

Comment: have you read the docs on Navigation?

Comment: @Jason, i know about using navigation controller but I'm getting on error when I tried that.
I've updated my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UI consistency error when calling iOS Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172290/ui-consistency-error-when-calling-ios-alert)

Comment: if you search on that error message you will get several helpful hints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are having is, you try to run UI related code inside async task. Do the navigation inside main thread

```
            BeginInvokeOnMainThread(
                () =>
                {
                    scannerView.StopScanning();
                    // Navigate code goes here
                });
```